# Unable to find any valid iOS distribution provisioning profiles in Appcelerator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am currently trying to build an application and have had endless problems since titanium has discontinued. Once at the last window of Provisioning, there is no profiles and when I browse to downloads for the latest from apple I am greeted with "Specified Provisioning Profile is invalid or is the wrong type".

I have also ran `appc ti info -t ios` in the terminal which states "Unable to find any valid iOS distribution provisioning profiles". So my question is how do I add a distribution provisioning profile? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Mistake, The reason being was the app ID was slightly different, trust me to spot it once the question was posted.